# Responsive jquery UI Datepicker

Tags: jquery

Is there a way to make Jquery Datepicker Responsive ? Because on small screens the calendar background gets resized but not the numbers.
Here is the problem: http://hpics.li/2286798
I found similiar problems on google but didn't find any good solution

Answer (score 0):

I do not know why you have such an effect. Please your code.
You can check my solution to jsFiddle.

```css
.ui-datepicker-calendar {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <script>
  $( function() {
    $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker();
  } );
  </script>
<div style="width: 100%">
  <p>Date: <input type="text" id="datepicker" style="width: 10px"></p>
</div>
```

You may apply bootstrap and set the datepicker tag `.col-4` then it should look nice.

See also css files, because it is possible that there overwrite datepicker default settings.

Comment: Weird :/ I used the CSS given with JQUERY UI and it didn't have any Datepicker-calendar in it. Adding it with 100% width fixed part of the problem now just the next month and previous month (the two arrows above the calendar) get almost on top of eachother. I tried modifing datepicker-header and datepicker next and prev but I can't find the solution. Do you have an idea ?

Comment: I found out I have to modify the .ui-datepicker .ui-datepicker-prev,
.ui-datepicker .ui-datepicker-next width. It's 1.8em what can I put instead of it ? 100% makes them look weird on normal screen size

Comment: Maybe Media queries ?

Comment: No prev and next are actually the size of the button's div in itself my problem is the header

Answer (score -1):

```
.ui-datepicker {
width: 17%;
padding: .2em .2em 0;
display: none;
}
.ui-datepicker-calendar {
width: 100%;
background-color: red;
}
.ui-datepicker .ui-datepicker-header {
position: relative;
padding: .2em 0;
width:100%;
}
.ui-datepicker-header{
width:100%;
}
.ui-datepicker .ui-datepicker-prev,
.ui-datepicker .ui-datepicker-next {
position: absolute;
top: 2px;
width: 1.8em;
height: 1.8em;
}
.ui-datepicker .ui-datepicker-prev-hover,
.ui-datepicker .ui-datepicker-next-hover {
top: 1px;
}
.ui-datepicker .ui-datepicker-prev {
left: 2px;
}
.ui-datepicker .ui-datepicker-next {
right: 2px;
}
.ui-datepicker .ui-datepicker-prev-hover {
left: 1px;
}
.ui-datepicker .ui-datepicker-next-hover {
right: 1px;
}
.ui-datepicker .ui-datepicker-prev span,
.ui-datepicker .ui-datepicker-next span {
display: block;
position: absolute;
left: 50%;
margin-left: -8px;
top: 50%;
margin-top: -8px;
}
.ui-datepicker .ui-datepicker-title {
margin: 0 2.3em;
line-height: 1.8em;
text-align: center;
}
.ui-datepicker .ui-datepicker-title select {
font-size: 1em;
margin: 1px 0;
}
.ui-datepicker select.ui-datepicker-month,
.ui-datepicker select.ui-datepicker-year {
width: 45%;
}
.ui-datepicker table {
width: 100%;
font-size: .9em;
border-collapse: collapse;
margin: 0 0 .4em;
}
.ui-datepicker th {
padding: .7em .3em;
text-align: center;
font-weight: bold;
border: 0;
}
.ui-datepicker td {
border: 0;
padding: 1px;
}
.ui-datepicker td span,
.ui-datepicker td a {
display: block;
padding: .2em;
text-align: right;
text-decoration: none;
}
.ui-datepicker .ui-datepicker-buttonpane {
background-image: none;
margin: .7em 0 0 0;
padding: 0 .2em;
border-left: 0;
border-right: 0;
border-bottom: 0;
}
.ui-datepicker .ui-datepicker-buttonpane button {
float: right;
margin: .5em .2em .4em;
cursor: pointer;
padding: .2em .6em .3em .6em;
width: auto;
overflow: visible;
}
.ui-datepicker .ui-datepicker-buttonpane button.ui-datepicker-current {
float: left;
}

/* with multiple calendars */
.ui-datepicker.ui-datepicker-multi {
width: auto;
}
.ui-datepicker-multi .ui-datepicker-group {
float: left;
}
.ui-datepicker-multi .ui-datepicker-group table {
width: 95%;
margin: 0 auto .4em;
}
.ui-datepicker-multi-2 .ui-datepicker-group {
width: 50%;
}
.ui-datepicker-multi-3 .ui-datepicker-group {
width: 33.3%;
}
.ui-datepicker-multi-4 .ui-datepicker-group {
width: 25%;
}
.ui-datepicker-multi .ui-datepicker-group-last .ui-datepicker-header,
.ui-datepicker-multi .ui-datepicker-group-middle .ui-datepicker-header {
border-left-width: 0;
}
.ui-datepicker-multi .ui-datepicker-buttonpane {
clear: left;
}
.ui-datepicker-row-break {
clear: both;
width: 100%;
font-size: 0;
}

/* RTL support */
.ui-datepicker-rtl {
direction: rtl;
}
.ui-datepicker-rtl .ui-datepicker-prev {
right: 2px;
left: auto;
}
.ui-datepicker-rtl .ui-datepicker-next {
left: 2px;
right: auto;
}
.ui-datepicker-rtl .ui-datepicker-prev:hover {
right: 1px;
left: auto;
}
.ui-datepicker-rtl .ui-datepicker-next:hover {
left: 1px;
right: auto;
}
.ui-datepicker-rtl .ui-datepicker-buttonpane {
clear: right;
}
.ui-datepicker-rtl .ui-datepicker-buttonpane button {
float: left;
}
.ui-datepicker-rtl .ui-datepicker-buttonpane button.ui-datepicker-current,
.ui-datepicker-rtl .ui-datepicker-group {
float: right;
}
.ui-datepicker-rtl .ui-datepicker-group-last .ui-datepicker-header,
.ui-datepicker-rtl .ui-datepicker-group-middle .ui-datepicker-header {
border-right-width: 0;
border-left-width: 1px;
}
```

Maybe seeing the CSS can help ?

Comment: This does not appear to answer the question. Did you mean to edit your question and put the CSS there?